# update or patch file for c# window application

Tags: c#, winforms

We have simple c# window application suppose which has lot of window `buttons`, `lables`, `text fields`, `list control`, `panel control`, `image` controls etc.

Each time when I change any button,label or any other changes into my window application

I want to send update or patch file(small size) to our client instead of whole EXE(large size) of c# window application. How is it possible?

i.e
exe size about:20mb
and new update file size should about:300kb-5mb

Comment: It would depend on how your application is designed. If everything resides in single executable, I would recommend fresh deployment rather than complicating it with anything else that will allow you to apply patch.

Comment: If I understand well your idea, please do not forget that it can be considered as "cracking" your own application and can lead to serious problems if you sign your application. I agree with updating via dll or via config - that can be stored in the DB/at some server and loaded at startup of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Group elements by your logic and move each of this groups into separate dll file. Make your program load this dlls dynamically and create patches only for dll files.

Answer (score 0):

Or dynamically load these options from a config file, then you only need to copy deploy that file.